# Calculation of Akaike Information Criterion

Tags: r, usage-statistics

My data file is given below.

```
Expt. (Col 1:2) Fit1 (Col 3:4)  Fit2 (Col 5:6)
x_expt. y_expt  x_fit   y_fit   x_fit   y_fit
2.89394 3.04606 2.95515 3.14485 2.96485 3.16485
2.90727 3.22788 2.96788 3.31939 2.97758 3.34061
2.92788 3.42545 2.98242 3.50303 2.99212 3.52606
2.97576 3.62303 2.99818 3.69758 3.00788 3.72182
2.97394 3.84182 3.01576 3.90182 3.02545 3.92848
3.00061 4.06364 3.03515 4.11818 3.04485 4.14606
3.02788 4.29939 3.05636 4.34545 3.06606 4.37515
3.05758 4.54848 3.08    4.58545 3.0897  4.61697
3.09455 4.80424 3.10606 4.83818 3.11576 4.87212
3.12909 5.07818 3.13515 5.10424 3.14485 5.14061
3.1697  5.37152 3.16667 5.38485 3.17758 5.42364
3.20727 5.65333 3.20182 5.68061 3.21273 5.72182
3.25394 5.98    3.24061 5.99152 3.25212 6.03576
3.30061 6.30909 3.28364 6.32121 3.29576 6.36364
3.35697 6.66061 3.33091 6.66667 3.34364 6.71515
3.41212 7.0303  3.38242 7.02424 3.39636 7.07879
3.47273 7.41818 3.44    7.40606 3.45455 7.46667
3.54606 7.82424 3.50303 7.81212 3.51818 7.87273
3.62242 8.24848 3.57212 8.2303  3.58909 8.29697
3.69939 8.69697 3.64788 8.67879 3.66667 8.74545
3.79212 9.16364 3.73152 9.14545 3.75212 9.21212
3.8903  9.66061 3.82364 9.6303  3.84545 9.70909
4.00242 10.1818 3.92424 10.1455 3.94848 10.2242
4.13212 10.6909 4.03455 10.6849 4.06121 10.7697
4.29697 11.2667 4.15576 11.2546 4.18485 11.3394
4.39273 11.8909 4.28788 11.8485 4.32061 11.9394
4.5503  12.5091 4.43273 12.4727 4.46848 12.5636
4.72061 13.2    4.59152 13.1212 4.63091 13.2242
4.89152 13.8424 4.76424 13.8061 4.80788 13.9091
5.07818 14.5636 4.95333 14.5212 5.00061 14.6303
5.30303 15.3212 5.15879 15.2667 5.21091 15.3818
5.54606 16.0788 5.38303 16.0485 5.44    16.1636
5.79212 16.8909 5.62667 16.8667 5.68848 16.9879
6.07273 17.7273 5.89212 17.7212 5.95939 17.8424
6.35152 18.6303 6.18182 18.6121 6.25455 18.7333
6.67879 19.5394 6.49091 19.5394 6.5697  19.6667
6.99394 20.4727 6.8303  20.503  6.91515 20.6364
7.42424 21.4485 7.19394 21.5091 7.28485 21.6424
7.73939 22.497  7.59394 22.5515 7.69091 22.6909
8.17576 23.5879 8.01818 23.6424 8.12121 23.7758
8.64242 24.7091 8.47879 24.7697 8.58788 24.903
9.12727 25.8242 8.97576 25.9394 9.09091 26.0788
9.59394 27.0727 9.50909 27.1515 9.6303  27.2909
10.1636 28.297  10.0788 28.4061 10.2061 28.5455
10.6909 29.5212 10.6909 29.7091 10.8242 29.8424
11.3939 31.0121 11.3455 31.0485 11.4909 31.1818
12.1152 32.4121 12.0485 32.4364 12.1939 32.5697
12.903  33.8667 12.8    33.8667 12.9455 34
13.6364 35.3515 13.5939 35.3455 13.7515 35.4667
14.4303 36.8546 14.4485 36.8606 14.6    36.9818
15.2849 38.5515 15.3515 38.4242 15.503  38.5394
16.2606 40.1939 16.3091 40.0303 16.4606 40.1455
17.2364 41.8909 17.3212 41.6788 17.4788 41.7879
18.3212 43.7091 18.3939 43.3697 18.5455 43.4727
19.4667 45.5576 19.5273 45.103  19.6788 45.2061
20.5152 46.8849 20.7212 46.8788 20.8667 46.9758
22.0606 49.1758 21.9818 48.6909 22.1152 48.7939
23.3152 51.1879 23.303  50.5515 23.4303 50.6485
24.7212 53.1576 24.6909 52.4485 24.8061 52.5455
26.2121 55.4727 26.1455 54.3879 26.2485 54.4849
```

a). Col 1:2 represent experimental data.
b). Col 3:4 is fitted data using non-linear least squares fitting using 4 adjustable parameters.
c). Col 5:6 is fitted data using non-linear least squares fitting using 5 adjustable parameters with one parameter fixed to 0.

I wish to calculate AIC for both the fits and conclude which fit is better. Can anybody suggest how to solve this problem in R or Excel?

Comment: You need the model in order to do this.  The predictions are not enough.  If you run the model in R, you can use AIC(model_object) to get the AIC.

Comment: actually, AIC could be recovered from the residual sums of squares. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Comparison_with_least_squares , `delta-AIC = 2*k + n*log(RSS)`